# Why does this jQuery code works only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this short jQuery code to make the picture disappear when the window is resized. For some reason, after it disappears, it doesn't appear again. 
Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){

        if($(window).width() < 700) {
            $("#side-pic").css("display","none");


        } else if($(window).width() >= 700){

            $("#side-pic").css("display","show");
        }

    });
    });
```

Also if by any chance you know if there is a way to make picture move under a certain div in my code, I'll be glad to hear it! Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: That's because the `"display","show"`. If you take a look at the CSS `display` property you'll see there's no `show` value.

Comment: RTM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 2):

There is no display property such as `display: show`. Try using `$("#side-pic").css("display","block");` instead.

Another Alternative would be hide/show:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){

        if($(window).width() < 700) {
             $("#side-pic").hide();
        } 
        else if($(window).width() >= 700) {
             $("#side-pic").show();
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `"show"` is not a valid `display` value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Also, why the `else if`, isn't an `else` good enough?
Or rather a reusable CSS class and jQuery's `toggleClass()` Method:

```js
jQuery( $ => {

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
      $("#side-pic").toggleClass("is-hidden", $(this).width() < 700);
  });

});
```

```css
.is-hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<div id="side-pic">SIDE PIC</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a code Like following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){

        if($(window).width() < 700) {
            $("#side-pic").hide();


        } else if($(window).width() >= 700){

            $("#side-pic").show();
        }

    });
});
```